# Nginx locations configuration

Tags: nginx

Let's say I have two upstreams: `upstream1` and `upstream2`.
Also I have API endpount `/api/thing`.
I want to configure two locations in nginx like this:

```
location /api/thing/? { 
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass http://upstream1;
        }

location /api/thing/* {
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass http://upstream2; }
```

In locations I used regular regexps (non-nginx configuration syntax):

1. Requests to /api/thing, /api/thing?param1=val1&param2=val2, etc should be proxied to upstream1
2. Requests to /api/thing/subthing1?a=b, /api/thing/subthing2/, etc should be proxied to upstream2

Is it possible in terms of nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
location = /api/thing {
  # upstream1
}

location = /api/thing/ {
  # upstream1
}

location /api/thing/ {
  # upstream2
}
```